# response using httpwebrequest and uri problems

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, getresponse

I'm trying to test if a website is up or down and I ran into some problems.

First I know if I'm to test the status of the server it's possible to do it with a simple piece of code like:

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping(TextBox1.Text) Then
        TextBox2.Text = "Online"
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = "Offline"
    End If
```

But i refuse to do so since Pings are not always a reliable method of determining if an external web server is up.

So i try to work this out using this code:

```
Try
        Dim fr As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim targetURI As New Uri(TextBox1.Text)
        fr = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(targetURI), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        If (fr.GetResponse().ContentLength > 0) Then
            TextBox2.Text = "Website appears to exist!"
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = "Website appears to have no content at all!"
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        TextBox2.Text = "Cannot connect - website not responding!"

End Try
```

That code works. But the problem is if I type `http://google.com` in the `TextBox1` and try to get server status then sometimes it shows up as *"Website appears to have no content at all!"* even when `http://google.com` is online and have contents. Not just for google but for other sites as well.

I have two question regarding this code.

1. Why does it tells me that *"Website appears to have no content at all!"* even when `http://google.com` or any other site is online and have contents?
2. Suppose i type in just `google.com` or any site without `http://` or `https://` in TextBox1 it gives me an error saying `invalid URI format`. Is there anyway I could automatically add `http://` or `https://` to the beginning of the url entered in TextBox1?

I know I can add this to the above code to do that:

```
Dim baseAddressx As String = "http://"
Dim targetURI As New Uri(baseAddressx & TextBox1.Text)
```

but what if I type `http://google.com` when the code it self adds `http://` that will make a problem. Any better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you should do is that you should read the Status Code of the response, not the content length. It can be read as follows:

`HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)fr.GetResponse();`
`int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode`
`if(statusCode == 200)`
`//Website is up else.`

You may create enums to have a good understanding of it. And respond in various ways to the user based on which value you get.
Hope that helps.

Sorry I am no expert in VB. I know C#, I hope you can convert this to VB easily. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! That did work. :) btw any answer for my second question?

Comment: As for the second part this is what will get your work done:

`string targetURIString = targetURI.toString();`
`if(targetURIString.Contains("http://")){`
`//then use the same URI.`
`}`
`else{`
`targetURIString += "http://" + targetURI;`
`//Use the second string.`
`}`

Comment: You may additionally check for "www" also in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, that worked as well. Thank you once again, I'm sure it'll come in handy in lots of situations. :)